# Como posso guardar a chave privada e publica para usar depois?sendo que o programa sempre gera chaves diferentes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, criptografia

Bom, gostaria de poder salvar a chave privada e a publica para usar depois para criptografar e se alguém quiser descriptografar minha mensagem, mas toda vez o programa gera uma nova chave.
Como posso salvar as chaves e depois usar ela depois para criptogragar ou descriptografar?

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import de

#gerando chave provada
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)

#gerando chave publica
public_key = private_key.public_key()

#Entrada do texto
mensagem = str(input("escreva uma mensagem:"))
bytes_mensagem = mensagem.encode('utf-8')

#Criptografando o texto
texto_cifrado = public_key.encrypt(
    bytes_mensagem,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
        label=None
    )
)
print(texto_cifrado)

# Descriptografando o texto
texto_descriptografado = private_key.decrypt(
    texto_cifrado,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
        label=None
    )

)
print(texto_descriptografado)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extraia os bytes a serem salvos da sua private key:

```
binary_data = private_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,           # codificacao
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,          # formato
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(), # para criptografar a chave
)
```

Grave os em um arquivo binário:

```
with open('minha_chave.rsa.key', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(binary_data)
```

Depois para ler novamente a chave, é só fazer o inverso, abra o arquivo e leia os bytes dele:

```
with open('minha_chave.rsa.key', 'rb') as f:
    binary_data = f.read()
private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    binary_data, password=None, backend=default_backend())
```